# How do you check if your bluetooth radio is bluetooth smart (ble) capable using a win32 app?

Tags: winapi, bluetooth-lowenergy

For more details, I'm using `BluetoothApis.h` and `WinSocks2.0` as well as `C++/WinRT` on a win32 app. I have all the connections finished but wanted to add a check for a Bluetooth low energy (BLE) capable radio before trying to connect. Unfortunately the `C++/WinRT` functions don't play very nice with win32 apps. [`Radio.GetRadiosAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios.radio.getradiosasync?view=winrt-20348) and [`BluetoothAdapter.GetRadioAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothadapter.getradioasync?view=winrt-20348#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_BluetoothAdapter_GetRadioAsync) both have to be compiled to a target architecture (see "Remarks" section on either page), which in my case, has to be a 32-bit machine due to a .dll that I am using, but if those functions don't work on 64-bit machines... I'm not familiar with how 64-bit machines run 32-bit apps.

My question is this; is there a way to check if a bluetooth radio is BLE capable? I've looked through the [bluetoothApis.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/) and found how to get radios, but I couldn't find a way to check for BLE capability. I've also looked through the [bluetoothLEApis.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothleapis/) but couldn't find anything related to the radio itself. If anyone has an idea, do tell.

Comment: The simples way to do that it just to check radio's HCI version.

Comment: "*Unfortunately the `C++/WinRT` functions don't play very nice with win32 apps*" - really? How so? "*I'm not familiar with how 64-bit machines run 32-bit apps*" - 64bit Windows runs a 32bit program inside of a 32bit emulator named WOW64, see [MSDN for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/running-32-bit-applications). As for as the program is concerned, it thinks it is running on a 32bit Windows (unless it is coded to be WOW64-aware).

Comment: @rem This is explicitly called out in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios.radio.getradiosasync): *"When this method is called from a desktop application (Win32), it will retrieve radio instances only when the application is natively compiled for the target architecture (in other words, when the application matches the computer architecture; so an x86 application running on an x64 architecture computer won't see any radio instances)."*

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks for the tip, I'll research more into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closer inspection, I noticed that there was another member function that can create a Bluetooth object.
The [`BluetoothAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothadapter?view=winrt-20348) class' [`GetDefaultAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothadapter.getdefaultasync?view=winrt-20348#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_BluetoothAdapter_GetDefaultAsync) function does NOT have the same restrictions as [`GetRadioAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios.radio.getradiosasync?view=winrt-20348) does. This is enough to retrieve the information on the Bluetooth low energy capabilities that I need.